# Run geth and mine in different locations?

Tags: go-ethereum, network

In one location I have renewable power, at my friend's place, but the internet is filtered, so p2p/geth seems to be blocked.

At home I have unfiltered net.

Is it possible to run geth at home (Windows), but mine at her place (Windows)?

Answer (score 1):

In order to mine, you need to build on currently existing blocks and transactions. Therefore you cannot mine offline.

From your mining machine you could however create a VPN or tunnel to some machine that is able to connect to other nodes [as described here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/3gfxo0/help_starting_geth_behind_firewall/). Otherwise you will not be able to create blocks that will be accepted by anyone else in the network (and you wont get usable block rewards).

Comment: If you mine through a pool you shouldn't need the blockchain, you only need a connection to the pool to request jobs and send solutions. The pool has to be connected to the blockchain, but can be in a remote location.

Comment: OP didnt mention using a pool but that is a good hint!